# Como fazer um programa em java que diga quais as posições a frente e atras de uma palavra

Tags: java, array, classificação

**Esse método diz quantas palavras se tem numa frase:**

```
public static int pesquisaPalavra(String palavra) {
    String frase = "Deus é bom o tempo todo, o tempo todo Deus é bom";
    String[] arrayString = frase.split(" ");

    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++) {

        if (arrayString[i].equals(palavra)) {
            cont++;
        }

    }

    return cont;

}
```

Quero ele diga quantas posições existem à frente e a trás da palavra encontrada.

**Chamada do metodo no `main`:**

```
public static void main(String ars[]) {
    System.out.println(pesquisaPalavra("Deus"));
}
```

Comment: Posições você diz seriam a quantidade de caracteres antes e depois da palavra?

Comment: E o que você já fez sobre isto? Qual sua dúvida específica (em oposição a ser geral e quer que as pessoas resolvam tudo sobre isso para você)?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer saber as posições das palavras que estão nesse array:

> `String[] arrayString = frase.split(" ");`

Fiz um exemplo bem simples com uma das maneiras que pode fazer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String frase = "Deus é bom o tempo todo, o tempo todo Deus é bom";

    System.out.println("Total de palavras encontradas: " + getQtdPalavras(frase, "Deus"));
}

public static int getQtdPalavras(String frase, String palavraPesquisada) {
    String[] palavras = frase.split(" ");

    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {

        if (palavras[i].equals(palavraPesquisada)) {
            System.out.println("Palavara >> " + palavraPesquisada + " << na posição >> " + i + " <<");
            System.out.println(posicoesAntes(i));
            System.out.println(posicoesDepois(palavras.length, i));
            System.out.println("\n");
            cont++;
        }

    }

    return cont;
}

public static String posicoesAntes(int posicaoAtual) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < posicaoAtual; i++) {
        sb.append(i).append(" ");
    }

    if ("".equals(sb.toString())) {
        sb.append("Não existem posições antes do item na posição ").append(posicaoAtual);
    }

    return "Posições antes: " + sb.toString();
}

public static String posicoesDepois(int length, int posicaoAtual) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = (posicaoAtual + 1); i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(i).append(" ");
    }

    if ("".equals(sb.toString())) {
        sb.append("Não existem posições depois do item na posição ").append(posicaoAtual);
    }

    return "Posições depois: " + sb.toString();
}
```